# What is a random-logic lexical scanner and what is tree-walking code generator?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, code-generation, lexical-analysis, spidermonkey

I'm studying [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey) internals. Its [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Internals#Compiler) says:

> The compiler consists of: a random-logic rather than table-driven
>   lexical scanner, a recursive-descent parser that produces an AST, and
>   a tree-walking code generator.

I don't know what a random-logic lexical scanner is and what a tree-walking code generator is. I searched "random-logic lexical scanner" and "tree-walking code generator" but didn't get anything that looked promising. Can I get a pointer to these concepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose what they mean by "random-logic lexical scanner" is that the lexical scanner was built by hand (or by many hands) rather than using a regular-expression-based table-driven lexical-scanner generator such as `(f)lex`. Presumably, the word is used as per the [hacker lexicon](http://www.outpost9.com/reference/jargon/jargon_33.html#SEC40), possibly acceptation 4 (incoherent, inelegant, disorganized) ["The program has a random set of misfeatures." "That's a random name for that function."] I'll refrain from further editorial comment.

Tree-walking is a pretty standard tool in code-generation, although few compilers are "pure" in the sense of being built from automatically-generated tree walkers and most serious compilers walk the tree more than once. While simple languages like Lua can be compiled directly during the parse, for most languages it is necessary to first build an abstract syntax tree (AST) and then do one or more walks over the tree. (Note: "abstract" in that phrase qualifies the word "syntax", not the word "tree". The AST is very concrete. English can be annoyingly ambiguous at times.)

Look at the LLVM documentation for many examples of tree walks, for example. Also, ANTLR will do automatic tree generation and there have been a number of attempts to automate or systematize code-generation with ANTLR; one example (which I haven't read so cannot either endorse or criticise) is AJ Admiraal's master's thesis ["Automated ANTLR Tree walker Generation"](http://fmt.cs.utwente.nl/files/sprojects/23.pdf) which I mention only because it was the first of a large number of hits from a Google search for "tree-walking code-generation".

Comment: Yeah.  JavaScript does not have a regular lexical grammar so most parsers for it are either scannerless, hand-written so that the parser gives hints to the lexer, or incorrect around `/` (division operators vs. regular expression literals) and nested template strings.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Not to mention the automatic semi-colon insertion rules. Certainly, JS requires an unfortunate coupling between lexical scanning and parsing, but it can be ring-fenced and implemented (correctly) as part of a flex/bison solution. Template parsing requires a recursive scan/parse, but that's no more difficult with flex/bison than without. Of course, the fact that something is possible doesn't make it obligatory (or even easy), and as I said earlier, I'm trying to refrain from editorial comment here.

Comment: semicolon insertion can be handled entirely at the parser level as long as the parser has access to line-terminator tokens and equivalent tokens (`/**...*/` with embedded line-terminator chars) and one token of non-space-comment token lookahead.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Sure, but it is another case of scanner-parser interconnect since normally the parser would not require any access to raw characters. I usually do this one by including a bit (or location information) with each token, which makes it possible for the parser to know whether or not two consecutive tokens are on the same line. Using different token types for tokens which do and do not start lines is also possible, but IMHO the grammar complication is not worthwhile. Similarly, you can pass line-terminator tokens and then mostly ignore them, but it makes the grammar harder to read.

Comment: I think I understand.  To restate: while it can be done in the parser, it may be simpler to fold a stream of tokens to tokens with meta-information that lets the parser identify places where semicolons can be; instead of complicating the grammar by explicitly matching  "ignorable" tokens as in `statement := expression (ignorables semi | negative_lookahead(ignorables (line_terminator | multiline-comment) ignorables (infix_operator | postfix_op | ...))`

Comment: @MikeSamuel: " JavaScript does not have a regular lexical grammar so most parsers for it are either scannerless, hand-written"  I can't speak for your statistics on how many JavaScript parsers you have specifically investigated.  I can tell your that our JavaScript front end uses an sophisticated but traditional style parser generator with explicit definitions of tokens with regular expressions.  (Some the sophistication makes it possible to handle the divide vs. regular-expression lexing; in fact, we part the regular expressions themselves).  ...

Comment: ... We use GLR parsing and special semantic reduction actions to handle semicolon insertion rules; rather than rici's "one bit" we simply stamp every token with a line number so it is each to check if two consecutive tokens are on the same line.   So, to emphasize  rici's point, JavaScript is parseable using good tooling, just fine.

Comment: "we part the regular expression" above s/b "we parse the regular expressions"

Comment: @IraBaxter, I never claimed ES wasn't parseable using good tooling, just that parser generators which assume that the input can be split with a single regular scanner won't work.  Since you asked for a survey of ES interpreters with hand-written parsers: [V8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/parser.cc#L1184), [SpiderMonkey](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/be1f49e80d2d/js/src/frontend/Parser.cpp#l2805), [JavaScriptCore](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/parser/Parser.cpp#L1136).  That covers 3 of 4 major browsers.  I don't know what Chakra/IE do.